# Is it okay to edit my answer based on another answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

Let's say someone asked a questions. I answered it with a good answer, got some upvotes, and now my answer is the most voted answer there.

All of a sudden, a smarter user post a better answer. My answer isn't wrong, it's just that his answer is better. I upvote his answer right away and here comes the dilema:

I don't really want to delete my answer because it still is a valid and good answer. But his answer is better and it might be too late for him to get enough upvotes to get to the top (note that OP hasn't accepted any answer yet).

Is it okay if I add an *edit* section within my answer to include the other answer in my answer (obviously giving the user his credit)? Is this a good thing to do or should I just stay passive and see if other users vote on his question?

Comment: You can always clearly cite. But I don't see really value doing so.

Comment: The value I see is the message sent: "Yo, even though my answer is the most voted, check out this other answer that is actually better than mine, or at least complements it". Many users tend to simply read the answer on top and ignore the others, specially if that first answer solves their problem.

Comment: Simply use his answer and make your answer a community wiki and site him.

Comment: Well, I'd say if your answer is *use different way, but do the same thing*. Then you don't need edit your answer just because his answer is using a simple, clear way. If you think there's some points in his answer and these can improve your answer, just edit and change them. But if you want change your answer *to his answer*. Then I'd suggest don't do that, that's useless for OP, others, and would be little...what's the license of our answers on [so]? :P

Comment: @KevinGuan It might be MIT in a while :P http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange

Answer (score 8):

If your answer isn't adding anything useful, in addition to what the other answer is providing, just delete your answer.  It doesn't matter if your answer is *correct*, if it's an universally worse solution then your answer is only ever harmful to people that read it; at best they're wasting their time if they find the other answer, at worst they're using a worse answer because they don't read on.

Editing your answer to just change the solution that you're using into a completely different solution that the other user posted wouldn't be appropriate.  Imagine someone going to all of the questions that you've answered and posting a copy of your answer.  Even if they cite you, this is not adding value.  Duplicating the solution isn't helping anyone.

Now, the above scenarios assume that the other answer is a fundamentally and significantly different answer that is universally better.  That won't always be the case.

If the other answer simply demonstrates a minor flaw in your answer that you can fix, while still maintaining the majority of your own original works, then it is entirely fine to edit your answer to improve it.  If you use the other user's solutions to those problems, then you would need to cite them appropriately.  As long as your answer is still largely your own original work at this point, then this isn't a problem.  It's only a problem if, after the edits, all, or almost all, of your original ideas are gone, leaving nothing but a copy of the other answer.

As an example, sometimes by posting a better answer someone else explains something about the problem/solution that you didn't touch on, and you could include an explanation of that concept (possibly in your own words) to address that shortcoming, or if they post a solution that is more general, and works in more cases than your answer does, then you could also edit your answer to generalize it (whether you use the other answer's approach or continue with your own).

As a third situation, if the other answer is a very different solution, but both solutions will potentially have merit to future readers (either because they're each better in different situations, different people may find the explanations clearer to them, etc.) and neither answer is strictly better than the other, than just don't do anything else.  There is a place for multiple good answers to questions, and different people can find each answer more useful to them.  Just make sure that there really are *reasonable* situations where one would find your answer better for them when faced with the problem described in the question.  If such situations seem impossible or extremely unlikely, then you're really in the first scenario I described.